# solr tika extraction problem

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am using tika with dataimporthandler. while executing the full-import I am getting the following errors.

```
SEVERE: Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:tika-test Processing Document # 1
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessor(DocBuilder.java:817)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:547)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:267)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:186)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:353)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:411)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:392)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load TikaEntityProcessor or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:1010)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessor(DocBuilder.java:814)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'TikaEntityProcessor'
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:1000)
            ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TikaEntityProcessor
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
            at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
```

In solrconfig.xml i write the configuration parameters as like this

```
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
              <lst name="defaults">
              <str name="config">/var/solr/data-config.xml</str>
             </lst>
        </requestHandler>
```

Where i am wrong? Can you guys help me. I am searching for this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Which Solr version are you using? Solr 1.4?
TikaEntityProcessor was added after 1.4:
http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg35902.html

Comment: I am using 1.4.1 and 3.2 also. In both versions it is showing the same error.The ticka version is 8.0

Comment: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor should be located inside **apache-solr-dataimporthandler-** _version_ **.jar**. If you unzip (rar) the jar, can you locate the class TikaEntityProcessor? Maybe your v3.2 installation uses jars from your 1.4.1 version?